# Проблема после переустановки Postgresql на Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Было выполнено удаление postgresql, с помощью команд:

```
sudo apt remove --purge postgresql    
sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql/
sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
sudo rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
sudo userdel -r postgres
sudo groupdel postgres
```

После установки postgresql

```
sudo apt install postgresql
```

И попытке запустить psql, возникает ошибка:

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
> Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

Каталога "var/run/postgresql" на диске нет.
Каким образом исправить ошибку?

Comment: данная ошибка не так страшна. В командной строке используйте `-h localhost` при условии, что 
 в pg разрешен доступ к localhost